# Identify patient visits to specific ICUs (e.g. PICU, NICU, CICU)

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm attempting to find patients that have visited specific ICUs at a hospital (either PICU, NICU, or CICU). 
I've looked at the `Encounter 2` resource and the `Location 3` resource but am not seeing anything that would:

1. Clearly identify a visit to an ICU and specify what type of ICU it was (PICU, CICU, NICU, etc)
2. Have the ability to search for patients by seeing who has visited said ICUs, possibly during a certain timeframe.
3. Find the Admission and Discharge dates to the ICU.

The closest I've found is the `ServiceType` on the `Encounter 2` resource which has the following options:

- Intensive Care Medicine
- Paediatric Intensive Care Medicine
- Neonatology & Perinatology

However, these are too general and don't directly provide the type of ICU or admission/discharge dates to the ICU.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish these goals are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a FHIR R4 question:
To capture the details of services available at a location you should use the [HealthcareService](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/healthcareservice.html) Resource. You then would search for all encounters of a location where a specific kind of service is available.

You mentioned Encounter.ServiceType only having insufficient options for your problem. This ValueSet is only an example binding. So you can replace it with a VS for your specific use-case.